# Как объединить 2 таблицы в одну с 2 полями MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить запрос. Мне необходимо из 2 таблиц выбрать одинаковые значения полей `userid` и `fuserid`.

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users, fusers WHERE a.userid=457281
AND b.fuserid=457281
```

выдает пустые поля `[userid][fuserid]`, хотя в `users` имеется 2 значения, в таблице `fuserid` пока не имеется значений

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users RIGHT JOIN fusers ON    
a.userid=457281 AND b.fuserid=457281
```

также выдает пустые поля `[userid][fuserid]`

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users LEFT JOIN fusers ON a.userid=457281  
AND b.fuserid=457281
```

выдает ненужное поле, к пример:

```
[userid][fuserid]
[457281][NULL]
[457281][NULL]
[391419][NULL]
```

лишнее поле, которое не нужно

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users JOIN fusers ON a.userid=457281
AND b.fuserid=457281
```

выдает пустые поля

Пи объединении с помощью `UNION`

```
(SELECT a.userid FROM users WHERE  a.userid=457281) UNION (SELECT
b.fuserid FROM fusers WHERE  b.fuserid=457281)
```

выдает одну колонку, имеющую значение 457281, в данном случае `[userid]`

Мне нужно, чтоб из 2-х таблиц выбирались одинаковые записи и показывались в разных колонках.
Типа:

```
[457281][457281] или 

[NULL][457281] или 

[457281][NULL]
```

Как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT max(userid) userid, max(fuserid) fuserid
  FROM (
    SELECT userid as id, userid, NULL as fuserid
      FROM users
     WHERE userid=457281
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fuserid     , NULL  , fuserid
      FROM fusers
     WHERE fuserid=457281
  ) X
  GROUP BY id
```

Если убрать условия на отбор конкретного id в таблицах, можно получить выборку по всем id, в которой будет видно какие из них присутствуют в какой из таблиц.

Answer (score 2):

Из вопроса непонятно, какой из двух случаев вам нужен.

Если вам нужно выбирать значение только тогда, когда оно есть в обоих таблицах, то проще всего сделать уже приведенный INNER JOIN

```
SELECT u.userid, f.fuserid
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN fusers AS f ON u.userid = f.fuserid AND f.fuserid = ?
```

Однако т.к. сам ID вам очевидно известен и вы явно проверяете только наличие записи, проще обратиться к соответствующим операторам

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users AS u WHERE u.userid = ?) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fusers AS f WHERE f.fuserid = ?)
```

Так запрос хотя бы сам по себе будет объяснять свое существование

В случае, если вам нужно проверить, есть ли это значение хотя бы в одной таблице, достаточно сделать FULL OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT COALESCE(u.userid, f.fuserid) AS result
FROM users AS u
FULL OUTER JOIN fusers AS f ON u.userid = f.fuserid AND f.fuserid = ?
```

Т.к. как верно замечают рядом, OUTER JOIN в MySQL еще не завезли, его можно грубо эмулировать через UNION

```
SELECT COALESCE(cte.userid, cte.fuserid) AS result 
FROM (
  SELECT u.userid, f.fuserid
  FROM users AS u
  LEFT JOIN fusers AS f ON u.userid = f.fuserid AND f.fuserid = ?
  UNION
  SELECT u.userid, f.fuserid
  FROM users AS u
  RIGHT JOIN fusers AS f ON u.userid = f.fuserid AND f.fuserid = ?
)
```

В этом случае вам вернется либо ноль строк, либо одна строка с одним полем.

EXISTS все так же работает (внимание на логический оператор):

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users AS u WHERE u.userid = ?) 
OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fusers AS f WHERE f.fuserid = ?)
```

Если же для вас критично получить результат или null, что, конечно, немного издевательски по отношению к SQL, достаточно будет прибегнуть к небольшому хаку:

```
SELECT COALESCE(u.userid, f.fuserid) AS result
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN fusers AS f ON u.userid = f.fuserid AND f.fuserid = ?
UNION
SELECT null AS result
```

Можно даже принудить SQL возвращать ровно одну строку:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(u.userid, f.fuserid) AS result
  FROM users AS u
  INNER JOIN fusers AS f ON u.userid = f.fuserid AND f.fuserid = ?
  UNION
  SELECT null AS result
) AS cte LIMIT 1
```

Но все это суть издевательство, и я бы все-таки посмотрел на EXISTS.

Comment: Ваши запросы действуют, но результат выдают не тот, который необходим, либо возвращают пустые строки. Мне нужно вывести записи под известным id в одну таблицу, включая и пустые. Так, имеется таблица с "вопросами" и таблица с "обращениями". Каждая из таблиц может быть пустой, а может иметь значения, в том числе id пользователя.  Таким образом мне нужен именно такой результат [457281][457281] или [NULL][457281] или [457281][NULL] т.е. если имеется записи в 2 таблицах от пользователя id, то это 1 случай, если нет, то 2 или 3 случай.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как-то так:

```
SELECT distinct a.userid, b.fuserid
FROM users a, fusers b
WHERE a.userid = 457281 AND (b.fuserid = 457281 OR b.fuserid is null)
      OR (a.userid = 457281 OR a.userid is null) AND b.fuserid = 457281
```

Comment: SELECT distinct q.questfromuid, f.fndfromuid FROM quest q LEFT JOIN find f ON q.questfromuid = 359837 AND (f.fndfromuid = 359837 OR f.fndfromuid IS NULL) OR (q.questfromuid = 359837 OR q.questfromuid IS NULL) AND f.fndfromuid = 359837 Выводит в таком виде, который необходим, но! помимо этого выводит строкой другой id. Как это можно избежать?

Comment: RIGHT JOIN выводит пустые строки, если одна таблица не заполнена

Comment: Сделай пример в sqlfiddle. И у меня в ответе full join, впрочем, он не может выводить меньше, чем другие.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, нужна для каждого ID только одна запись (посмотреть, есть ли записи в какой-то одной или обеих таблицах).

Поскольку MySQL не знает про FULL OUTER JOIN, то, видимо

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.userid, t2.fuserid
FROM (  SELECT userid u FROM users
        UNION
        SELECT fuserid FROM fusers
     ) t0
LEFT JOIN users t1 ON t0.u = t1.userid
LEFT JOIN fusers t2 ON t0.u = t2.fuserid
-- WHERE t0.u IN (список интересующих ID)
```

WHERE можно при желании убрать в подзапрос - если список мал, а записей много, это даст эффект.

Если интересует строго один ID, подзапрос t0 заменить на

```
( SELECT 123456 u ) t0
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT quest.questfromuid, find.fndfromuid FROM 
(SELECT quest.questfromuid u FROM quest
UNION
SELECT find.fndfromuid FROM find
) t0
LEFT JOIN quest t1 ON t0.u = t1.questfromuid
LEFT JOIN find t2 ON t0.u = t2.fndfromuid
WHERE t0.u IN (359837)  #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'quest.questfromuid' в 'field list'

Comment: *рукалицо* `SELECT DISTINCT t1.questfromuid, t2.fndfromuid`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT users.userID, fusers.fuserID
FROM users
INNER JOIN fusers ON users.userID = 1 and fusers.fuserID = 1
```

Comment: Yes, it is true, but I need to choose with a certain id, for example 415519 and that this id was either in users.userID and fusers.fuserID FOR EXAMPLE: SELECT users.userID, fusers.fuserID FROM users INNER JOIN fusers ON users.userID = fusers.fuserID WHERE users.userID=415519 AND fusers.fuserID=415519.

Comment: Поменял код ,попробуй с помощью and

Comment: Ответ неверен. Не учтена фраза *в таблице fuserid пока не имеется значений*

Comment: Все верно, Akina. В таблице userid также может не быть значений ПОКА, как и в таблице fuserid, т.е набор значений переменный.

Answer (score -2):

Во всех ваших запросах вы забыли поставить алиасы на таблицы.
Вот рабочий запрос

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users a, fusers b WHERE a.userid=457281
AND b.fuserid=457281
```

или как вам уже ответили с добавлением условия

```
SELECT u1.id as u1_id, u2.id as u2_id FROM users u1
JOIN fusers u2 ON u1.id = u2.id
WHERE u1.id = 457281;
```

Comment: Ответ неверен. Не учтена фраза *в таблице fuserid пока не имеется значений*